# how to count the nodes in a linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

*this is my code but im not being able to count the nodes in the list, ive also given the test cases below those test cases should get executed*

```
class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.head = None
    tail=None
    list=[]
    for x in a:
      if x not in list:
        list+=[x]
      if len(a)!=len(list):
        print("all keys are not unique")
      if len(a)==0:
        print("Array is empty.")
      else:
        for x in a:
          newNode = Node(x, None)
          if (self.head == None):
            self.head = newNode
            tail = newNode
          else:
            tail.next = newNode
            tail = newNode
   
  # Count the number of nodes in the list
  def countNode(self):
    self.head= None
    
    pass # Remove this line
```

**test cases**

```
print("////// Test 01 //////")
a1 = [10, 20, 30, 40]
h1 = LinkedList(a1) # Creates a linked list using the values from the array
# head will refer to the Node that contains the element from a[0]

h1.printList() # This should print: 10,20,30,40
print(h1.countNode()) # This should print: 4
```

Comment: you should also include your `Node` code

Comment: Why do you expect your code to work? Your function does nothing. Did you try yourself before asking here?

Comment: why am i here to ask the questions obv my code isnt working nah thats why im here to ask for help. if u cant help u can ignore. you dont have to say oh you have run it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your `Node` looks like this

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, next_=None):
        self.element = val
        self.next = next_ # you should use next_ 


@property
def countNode(self):
    temp = self.head
    cnt = 0
    while temp:
        cnt += 1
        temp = temp.next


def printList(self):
    temp = self.head
    while temp:
        print(temp.element)  # if Node contains val for value
        temp = temp.next
```

Going along with your code,

```
h1 = LinkedList(a1)
# for count -> h1.countNode
# for print -> h1.printList()
```

Comment: ```class Node:
  def __init__(self, e, n):
    self.element = e
    self.next = n ```    this is my node code, how to do now ok got it thanks

Comment: updated the code, now check